# How can I prevent the form on my mobile website from floating right in landscape view everytime I select an input field?

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile, media-queries

I have tried using float, overflow, clear and yet still my html form continues floating right. My intended outcome is for the html form to remain in portrait on my mobile device when I go to fill out the form.

This is the current code for my html form:

```
<form name = "CommentsForm" action ="Actionpage.php" onsubmit="return       
validateForm()" method="post">
<u class = "FormHeading">Send Comment</u><br>
<br>
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
<div style = "position: relative; top: 4px; left: 01px;">
Last Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</div>
<br>
<div style = "position: relative; top: -13px; left: 1px;">
 Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email">
</div>
<br>
<div style = "position: relative; top: -24px; left:03px;">
<label for="comment"> Comment:</label></div>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Type commment              
here" style="height: 69px;">
</textarea>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Send" >
</form>
```

This is the css for the html form on my mobile website:

```
form 
{ 
 border: 10px solid #D3D3D3; 
 border-radius: 4px;
 background: #D3D3D3;
 width: 176px;
 height: 319px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 620px; 
 left: 91px;
 font-family: "Arial", "Times New Roman", "Sans Serif"; 
 font-style: normal;
 text-decoration: none;
 float: none;
 }
.FormHeading
{
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
 left: 29px;
 }
 input[type=text]
 {
 width: 168px;
 float: none;
 }
 input[type=text]:focus
 {
 float: none;
 }
 textarea
 {
 resize: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 top: -23px;
 left: 01px;
width: 173px;
float: none;
}

input[type=submit]
{
background-color: #ADD8E6;
position: relative;
top: -44px;
left: 119px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Please note I have a HTC desire 626 and I am designing my mobile website with this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing a pen with a posible solution:

Your positions where fixed, so I made them flexible using percentages.
Let me know if its ok.

[Click for Solution at codepen](https://codepen.io/coloripop/pen/YOGdvM)

```css
form {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  width: 176px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 319px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-family: "Arial", "Times New Roman", "Sans Serif";
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.FormHeading {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 29px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 168px;
  float: none;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  float: none;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  top: -23px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 173px;
  float: none;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #add8e6;
  position: relative;
  top: -44px;
  left: 119px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=submit]
{
background-color: #ADD8E6;
position: relative;
top: -44px;
left: 119px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form name="CommentsForm" action="Actionpage.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <u class="FormHeading">Send Comment</u><br>
  <br> First Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  <div style="position: relative; top: 4px; left: 01px;">
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="position: relative; top: -13px; left: 1px;">
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="position: relative; top: -24px; left:03px;">
    <label for="comment"> Comment:</label></div>
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Type commment here" style="height: 69px;"></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but unfortunately the code hasn't fixed my issue. It only changed the original position of my form on my mobile website home page.

Comment: Could you send me an screenshot of your problem please, I can't get the problem yet. You can upload an image to http://es.tinypic.com/ and send the link

Comment: Original position of the form: http://tinypic.com/r/2afkc49/9 . The unwanted change of position for the form: http://tinypic.com/r/2iatvte/9

Answer (score 0):

use your form properties like this:

```
form { border: 10px solid #D3D3D3; border-radius: 4px; background: #D3D3D3; width: 176px; height: 319px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; font-family: "Arial", "Times New Roman", "Sans Serif"; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; }
```

I have removed your float and made position relative and added margin: 0 auto;
I guess you are trying to keep the form in the middle of the screen? If yes, then this will work.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help. But the form still moves to the right unfortunately.